# jQuery scrollTop() stops working

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('#staff_list').scroll(function(){
    var dif = scrollPrev - $('#staff_list').scrollTop();
    scrollPrev = $('#staff_list').scrollTop();
    var pos = parseInt($('.selected').css('margin-top')) + dif;
    var limit = $('.selected').position().top + parseInt($('.selected').css('margin-top'));

    if( limit < 474 ) {
        $('.selected').css('margin-top',pos + 'px');
    } 

});
```

The code is suppose to ensure `$('.selected')` moves with `$('#staff_list')` when the list is scrolled. However, I want to limit how much `$('.selected')` moves and keep at a bound at the bottom of the list.

Everything works, except when I reach the bottom limit, the `$('.selected')` stops moving (as it should), but then completely stops! So even if I scroll back up, it no longer moves. It is as though when it reaches the limit, then it forever stays there, no matter what I do!

What could cause this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var limit = $('.selected').position().top + parseInt($('.selected').css('margin-top'));

if( limit < 474 ) {
    $('.selected').css('margin-top',pos + 'px');
}
```

Once `limit` is greater than 474, you will never change the position, hence `limit` will never be less than 474. Perhaps you meant `if(pos < limit)`?

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to determine whether to move the element based on where the element is. So once that element reaches a point where it's not supposed to move, it simply stops moving (either direction).

Try calculating whether `.selected` should move based on the `scrollTop` of `#staff_list` instead.

edit - Try changing

`var limit = $('.selected').position().top + parseInt($('.selected').css('margin-top'));`

To

`var limit = pos + parseInt($('.selected').css('margin-top'));`